# How to add a custom metabox to the Menu Management admin screen?

Tags: wp-admin, menus, functions, hierarchical

Although I am very thankful to the wordpress core team that they have finally integrated native menu management capabilities I get frustrated with some key elements which I would like to change.

I need a way of showing pages which is hierarchical in the same way hierarchical categories are displayed instead of being in a list and I need a way of manually including links which can be added to a menu.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATED**
So, here are the two things I am trying to do. Currently if you go to the default wordpress "menu management" admin screen you can select to display the "pages" metabox on the left. The problem here is that when you click on the "view all" tab NONE of the pages are ordered correctly and they are not indented if applicable.

**CURRENT DEFAULT LAYOUT:**

[image: CURRENT DEFAULT WP ORGANIZATION]

**DESIRED LAYOUT:** (please note that I just indented them to show the parent relationship, the items should also be sorted based on their sort order).

[image: what i would like]

Additionally, within this list (or if easier then within its own metabox) I need some way of hard coding links which should be presented in the form of a checkbox list so one can click elements and include them within the menu. The reason for this is that instead of having to manually add these elements using the "custom links" I would prefer to select them from a list.

Comment: Can you formulate this in the form of one question?

Comment: I have modified the question as suggested

Comment: I meant in the title. The headline sounds like a statement and not like a question.

Comment: @hakre -- thanks, done. Do you happen to have a suggestion on this?

Comment: Probably: "How to add a custom metabox to the Menu Management admin screen?"

Comment: @hakre -- suggestion implimented

Comment: The metabox you ask about, should it be on the left side and contain stuff that you can create menu entries of then?

Comment: Can you add a picture that shows what you actually want to achieve. Each time I run over this question I ask myself what exactly you want to do. Manually adding links to the menu should be possible already for example.

Comment: @hakre - sure, I will put sometime together shortly

Comment: @hakre -- hi hakre! I am not sure if I userstood your nov. 12th comment but let me explain the wordpress usage flaw. I use custom post types a great deal and extended them to allow for custom archive templates to be used when the post types slug is visited. All this works fine but when using the default wordpress menu manager these have to be added manually through custom fields. This confuses non developers so I was hoping there was a way to manage custom links which can be added through checkboxes. The cool bonus would be a way to manage these custom links from a restricted capability GUI.

Comment: The other topic also related to a stupid wordpress usability flaw. For the metaboxes listed on the left of the menu manager interface, all page lists are NOT sorted or indented with parent/child relationships... For me this is just annoying so I hope there is a simple code fix.

Comment: @NetConstructor: I'm by far a CPT expert. I very much dislike this very limited feature that even hasn't made it into wp.com and even with 3.1 won't make it. So you are probably adressing your comments to the wrong person, sorry. If you have decent feedback, it can help to discuss issue with the UI team in their mailinglist: http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-ui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I succeeded in this, but it is a mess. Basically, the walker should have the following parameters:

```
$this->db_fields['parent'] = 'post_parent';
$this->db_fields['id'] = 'ID';
```

But, to get that in place, you need to rip out the existing metabox callback, copy it, change one line so you get an extra filter, and place it back. Then you can pass your own walker that has these parameters set.

```
add_filter( 'admin_head-nav-menus.php', 'wpse2770_admin_head_nav_menus' );
function wpse2770_admin_head_nav_menus()
{
    // Hijack "Pages" meta box callback with one that has an extra filter for the walker class
    $GLOBALS['wp_meta_boxes']['nav-menus']['side']['default']['add-page']['callback'] = 'wpse2770_wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box';

    // Since Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist is not always available, we create this class in this function (didn't even know that was possible...)
    class WPSE2770_Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist extends Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db_fields['parent'] = 'post_parent';
            $this->db_fields['id'] = 'ID';
        }
    }

}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box_walker', 'wpse2770_wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box_walker', 10, 3 );
function wpse2770_wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box_walker( $walker, $post_type, $context )
{
    if ( 'page' == $post_type && 'view-all' == $context ) {
        $walker = 'WPSE2770_Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist';
    }
    return $walker;
}

function wpse2770_wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box( $object, $post_type ) {
    global $_nav_menu_placeholder, $nav_menu_selected_id;

    $post_type_name = $post_type['args']->name;

    // paginate browsing for large numbers of post objects
    $per_page = 50;
    $pagenum = isset( $_REQUEST[$post_type_name . '-tab'] ) && isset( $_REQUEST['paged'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['paged'] ) : 1;
    $offset = 0 < $pagenum ? $per_page * ( $pagenum - 1 ) : 0;

    $args = array(
        'offset' => $offset,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
        'post_type' => $post_type_name,
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false
    );

    if ( isset( $post_type['args']->_default_query ) )
        $args = array_merge($args, (array) $post_type['args']->_default_query );

    // @todo transient caching of these results with proper invalidation on updating of a post of this type
    $get_posts = new WP_Query;
    $posts = $get_posts->query( $args );
    if ( ! $get_posts->post_count ) {
        echo '<p>' . __( 'No items.' ) . '</p>';
        return;
    }

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post_type_name);

    $num_pages = $get_posts->max_num_pages;

    $page_links = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg(
            array(
                $post_type_name . '-tab' => 'all',
                'paged' => '%#%',
                'item-type' => 'post_type',
                'item-object' => $post_type_name,
            )
        ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'total' => $num_pages,
        'current' => $pagenum
    ));

    if ( !$posts )
        $error = '<li id="error">'. $post_type['args']->labels->not_found .'</li>';

    $walker = 'Walker_Nav_Menu_Checklist';

    $current_tab = 'most-recent';
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[$post_type_name . '-tab'] ) && in_array( $_REQUEST[$post_type_name . '-tab'], array('all', 'search') ) ) {
        $current_tab = $_REQUEST[$post_type_name . '-tab'];
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['quick-search-posttype-' . $post_type_name] ) ) {
        $current_tab = 'search';
    }

    $removed_args = array(
        'action',
        'customlink-tab',
        'edit-menu-item',
        'menu-item',
        'page-tab',
        '_wpnonce',
    );

    ?>
    <div id="posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>" class="posttypediv">
        <ul id="posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-tabs" class="posttype-tabs add-menu-item-tabs">
            <li <?php echo ( 'most-recent' == $current_tab ? ' class="tabs"' : '' ); ?>><a class="nav-tab-link" href="<?php if ( $nav_menu_selected_id ) echo esc_url(add_query_arg($post_type_name . '-tab', 'most-recent', remove_query_arg($removed_args))); ?>#tabs-panel-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-most-recent"><?php _e('Most Recent'); ?></a></li>
            <li <?php echo ( 'all' == $current_tab ? ' class="tabs"' : '' ); ?>><a class="nav-tab-link" href="<?php if ( $nav_menu_selected_id ) echo esc_url(add_query_arg($post_type_name . '-tab', 'all', remove_query_arg($removed_args))); ?>#<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-all"><?php _e('View All'); ?></a></li>
            <li <?php echo ( 'search' == $current_tab ? ' class="tabs"' : '' ); ?>><a class="nav-tab-link" href="<?php if ( $nav_menu_selected_id ) echo esc_url(add_query_arg($post_type_name . '-tab', 'search', remove_query_arg($removed_args))); ?>#tabs-panel-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-search"><?php _e('Search'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-panel-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-most-recent" class="tabs-panel <?php
            echo ( 'most-recent' == $current_tab ? 'tabs-panel-active' : 'tabs-panel-inactive' );
        ?>">
            <ul id="<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>checklist-most-recent" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php
                $recent_args = array_merge( $args, array( 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 15 ) );
                $most_recent = $get_posts->query( $recent_args );
                $args['walker'] = new $walker;
                echo walk_nav_menu_tree( array_map('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $most_recent), 0, (object) $args );
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.tabs-panel -->

        <div class="tabs-panel <?php
            echo ( 'search' == $current_tab ? 'tabs-panel-active' : 'tabs-panel-inactive' );
        ?>" id="tabs-panel-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-search">
            <?php
            if ( isset( $_REQUEST['quick-search-posttype-' . $post_type_name] ) ) {
                $searched = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['quick-search-posttype-' . $post_type_name] );
                $search_results = get_posts( array( 's' => $searched, 'post_type' => $post_type_name, 'fields' => 'all', 'order' => 'DESC', ) );
            } else {
                $searched = '';
                $search_results = array();
            }
            ?>
            <p class="quick-search-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="quick-search input-with-default-title" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Search'); ?>" value="<?php echo $searched; ?>" name="quick-search-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>" />
                <img class="waiting" src="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'images/wpspin_light.gif' ) ); ?>" alt="" />
                <?php submit_button( __( 'Search' ), 'quick-search-submit button-secondary hide-if-js', 'submit', false ); ?>
            </p>

            <ul id="<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-search-checklist" class="list:<?php echo $post_type_name?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $search_results ) && ! is_wp_error( $search_results ) ) : ?>
                <?php
                $args['walker'] = new $walker;
                echo walk_nav_menu_tree( array_map('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $search_results), 0, (object) $args );
                ?>
            <?php elseif ( is_wp_error( $search_results ) ) : ?>
                <li><?php echo $search_results->get_error_message(); ?></li>
            <?php elseif ( ! empty( $searched ) ) : ?>
                <li><?php _e('No results found.'); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.tabs-panel -->


        <div id="<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>-all" class="tabs-panel tabs-panel-view-all <?php
            echo ( 'all' == $current_tab ? 'tabs-panel-active' : 'tabs-panel-inactive' );
        ?>">
            <?php if ( ! empty( $page_links ) ) : ?>
                <div class="add-menu-item-pagelinks">
                    <?php echo $page_links; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>checklist" class="list:<?php echo $post_type_name?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">
                <?php
                // WPSE 2770: And this is the filter we want to add!
                $walker = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_item_post_type_meta_box_walker', $walker, $post_type_name, 'view-all' );
                $args['walker'] = new $walker;

                // if we're dealing with pages, let's put a checkbox for the front page at the top of the list
                if ( 'page' == $post_type_name ) {
                    $front_page = 'page' == get_option('show_on_front') ? (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' ) : 0;
                    if ( ! empty( $front_page ) ) {
                        $front_page_obj = get_post( $front_page );
                        $front_page_obj->_add_to_top = true;
                        $front_page_obj->label = sprintf( _x('Home: %s', 'nav menu front page title'), $front_page_obj->post_title );
                        array_unshift( $posts, $front_page_obj );
                    } else {
                        $_nav_menu_placeholder = ( 0 > $_nav_menu_placeholder ) ? intval($_nav_menu_placeholder) - 1 : -1;
                        array_unshift( $posts, (object) array(
                            '_add_to_top' => true,
                            'ID' => 0,
                            'object_id' => $_nav_menu_placeholder,
                            'post_content' => '',
                            'post_excerpt' => '',
                            'post_title' => _x('Home', 'nav menu home label'),
                            'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'url' => home_url('/'),
                        ) );
                    }
                }
$args['walker']->db_fields['parent'] = 'post_parent';
                $checkbox_items = walk_nav_menu_tree( array_map('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', $posts), 0, (object) $args );

                if ( 'all' == $current_tab && ! empty( $_REQUEST['selectall'] ) ) {
                    $checkbox_items = preg_replace('/(type=(.)checkbox(\2))/', '$1 checked=$2checked$2', $checkbox_items);

                }

                echo $checkbox_items;
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php if ( ! empty( $page_links ) ) : ?>
                <div class="add-menu-item-pagelinks">
                    <?php echo $page_links; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- /.tabs-panel -->


        <p class="button-controls">
            <span class="list-controls">
                <a href="<?php
                    echo esc_url(add_query_arg(
                        array(
                            $post_type_name . '-tab' => 'all',
                            'selectall' => 1,
                        ),
                        remove_query_arg($removed_args)
                    ));
                ?>#posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>" class="select-all"><?php _e('Select All'); ?></a>
            </span>

            <span class="add-to-menu">
                <img class="waiting" src="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'images/wpspin_light.gif' ) ); ?>" alt="" />
                <input type="submit"<?php disabled( $nav_menu_selected_id, 0 ); ?> class="button-secondary submit-add-to-menu" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Add to Menu'); ?>" name="add-post-type-menu-item" id="submit-posttype-<?php echo $post_type_name; ?>" />
            </span>
        </p>

    </div><!-- /.posttypediv -->
    <?php
}
```

Comment: thanks Jan. I can't believe how complicated it is to change this. Any idea if 3.1 resolves this?

Comment: @NetConstructor: I think I even created this against 3.1 beta 1, so no, it has not been changed. [The current trunk code still uses no filter.](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php?rev=16452#L824) Feel free to create a ticket.

Comment: resolved in V3.3

Answer (score 1):

This is something that should be put into a ticket on WordPress Trac for the UI group to go over. http://core.trac.wordpress.org/

(*Edit:* Related Ticket is [#14660 - Hierarchical Page List in wp-admin/nav-menus.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14660))

Comment: agreed but I am looking for a way to do this by means of code

Comment: resolved in V3.3