# Adding Pages to Menus - No Page Hierarchy in Backend

Tags: menus, pages, hierarchical, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a custom metabox to the Menu Management admin screen?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/how-to-add-a-custom-metabox-to-the-menu-management-admin-screen)

In the backend of Wordpress, under Appearance -> Menus it allows you to add different post types by clicking on checkboxes and then "Add to Menu". Normally it will display Pages, Posts, and Custom Links - it will also display Custom Post types that are added.

Pages are based on hierarchy, however in the list they are not organized this way. This makes it difficult if you have many pages with the same name (that are common subpages of unique parents).

Is there anyway to modify this behaviour to add hierarchy to the listing? Is there a wordpress function that can be overwritten, or even a new module that can be added to support Page hierarchy in the Menu section?

Comment: Same question asked here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/how-to-add-a-custom-metabox-to-the-menu-management-admin-screen

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to me, too.

Comment: How is it a duplicate if there was never an answer for it, or a way to comment on it even?

Comment: It's a duplicate because it's the same question. That doesn't mean it's a bad question, just that we should have the answers all on one question. Voting to close.

Comment: Duplicate now has answers.

Answer (score -1):

The new to Wordpress 3.0 Menu's can be made into a hierarchal structure by dragging the menu items to the left or right. I found a user guide on the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) that you may find helpful.

> The WordPress menu editor allows you
>   to create multi-level menus using a
>   simple ‘drag and drop’ interface. You
>   can drag menu items up or down to
>   change their order of appearance in
>   the menu, or you can drag them left or
>   right in order to create a multi-level
>   menu structure. To make one menu item
>   a subordinate of another item, then
>   position it underneath, and drag it
>   slightly to the right of, the main
>   menu item.

There are some [helpful screen shots](http://codex.wordpress.org/File%3awp3menu-screen6.png) in the guide to help you along your way.

Comment: As far as I understand question is about list of pages in the meta box you choose them from, not menu itself.

Comment: Correct, I understand how to make a menu hierarchical, its the "Pages" module on the left side that isn't listed hierarchical.